Redirect url without all payload and endpoint?
I have an angular application with 2 spring boot application: A and B
Actually angular call api from server A
I want to change that.
I would like angular do call api from server B and this last server call server A

There is a way to do so. But it is not called redirect. First of all, here is a very good (and short) guide to redirect and forward requests in spring boot: A Guide To Spring Redirects. But it looks like that's what you are looking for is that server B upon receiving request will get some (or none) of the incoming data from the original request and make an independent call to one of the end-points of server A. If this is the case, than you might want to send a regular HTTP request from your server B to your server A using any HTTP client. In other words the code within your server B endpoint will be an HTTP client to Server A. There are built-in tools in Spring boot such as Rest Template and WebClient. You can also use standalone HTTP clients such as Apache HTTP Client or OK HTTP Client.
Also, I actually wrote my own HTTP client. And while it doesn't provide the width of support for all the corner cases it is very simple to use for something basic of what you might want to do. This HTTP client is part of MgntUtils Open Source java library written and maintained by me. Here is the HTTP client Javadoc. The library artifacts can be found on Maven Central or as Jar file (with source code and Javadoc as separate files) on GitHub

if i use RestTemplate or tool like that, i will need to add call manually for every endpoint

To redirect a URL without including the payload and endpoint, you would typically use a HTTP 301 or 302 redirect status code. This would instruct the client's browser or user agent to fetch the resource from a different URL. The redirected URL should contain only the necessary information for the server to process the request correctly without including any additional payload or endpoint specifics. This approach helps maintain clean and efficient URL structures while ensuring proper navigation for users or applications.
